# How can I get a temperature sensor on my gnome panel in Ubuntu?

Tags: applet

I would like a gnome applet that shows the current temperature inside the laptop. Currently I use gkrellm but it takes up too much space on my desktop.

I tried installing 'sensors-applet' but the applet did not appear in the list of things to add when I right click on the gnome panel and select 'add to panel'.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Do you want to program one yourself or are you after a recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting your computer.  I know it sounds silly for Linux, but I just installed it (read the post and realized I wanted it too!), couldn't add it, and gave it a restart.  Works great now.

Comment: I found that I just had to kill gnome-panel. It automatically restarted itself and now I can add the sensors applet.